Добавление данных в JSON файл
Какой метод лучше подходит для добавления данных в json файл? Насколько я понял fs.reader можно использовать до тех пор, пока файл не станет больше 100мб, тогда какое решение лучше подойдет для того случая, когда файл будет бесконечно заполняться какими-то данными?

БД?​

Использование json файла в качестве БД

А если файл будет на 3ТБ? Ты же сам спрашиваешь решение в случае бесконечных данных...Ответ: БД
